# Running Redis rq worker on Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, redis, docker-compose

I am trying to make a queue of tasks using redis rq. I was trying to follow a tutorial but I am using docker. Below is my code-

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
import redis
from rq import Queue

import time
app = Flask(__name__)

r = redis.Redis()
q = Queue(connection=r)

def background_task(n):

    """ Function that returns len(n) and simulates a delay """

    delay = 2

    print("Task running")
    print(f"Simulating a {delay} second delay")

    time.sleep(delay)

    print(len(n))
    print("Task complete")

    return len(n)

def index():

    if request.args.get("n"):

        job = q.enqueue(background_task, request.args.get("n"))

        return f"Task ({job.id}) added to queue at {job.enqueued_at}"

    return "No value for count provided"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Docker compose file-

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
     
      
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

Whenever I run '''docker-compose up --build''' and open http://localhost:5000/ I get Url not found
Where am I going wrong?
How is one supposed to use rq worker command in docker containers.

Comment: I am new to using redis in docker so any tutorial links to that would help as well

Answer (score -1):

```
redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

The issue is that the image specified in your Docker compose YAML should be the image built by your Dockerfile.

The string passed here is the "[Docker-image name]:[tag]".

- Services configuration documentation page: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#image
- Redis docker image, public repository (Docker Hub) page, for allowable tags reference: https://hub.docker.com/_/redis

Without configuration, docker will use a default repository Docker Hub. To specify a custom/local repository, use this syntax:

```
image: my_private.registry:5000/redis
```

Because you have a dockerfile you want to use for this image you can specify it in-line, see the documentation here:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./dir
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-alternate
      args:
        buildno: 1
```

To clarify, there are two different approaches to using your own Dockerfile:

- Building a Docker image once, and publishing it to a local/private repository (*You will need to note/save the image name produced by the "docker build" command.*)
- Building your Docker image every time you run your Docker Compose build - This is the "in-line" approach, using the syntax directly above.

As a good practice, instead of calling your service "redis" in the docker compose file, you should provide a custom name to represent your worker script (your program). This is because you do not want naming confusion: here you are naming the Docker Compose Service, and only under the "image" configuration, specifying a Docker image (presumably the image built by your custom Dockerfile).